# How to preview a file in a pop up window in the community page LWC Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

I'm stuck to that issues and don't know how to fix that, so As I know standard library such as 'NavigationMixin' for file preview won't correctly work in the community page, so that code won't work

```
const docId = 'testcontdocid'
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'standard__namedPage',
  attributes: {
      pageName: 'filePreview'
  },
  state : {
      selectedRecordId: docId
  }
})
```

Anyway i found a solution, its to create corresponding record in 'ContentDistribution' object and DistributionPublicUrl field on contentDistribution gets populated automatically. then i can use it something like that:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: DistributionPublicUrl
        }
    });
```

And it works perfect, but opens the file in the new browser window, not in popup window. Does anyone knows how to fix that? Thanks in advance. By the way i use lwc

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer? I'm stuck in this too

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and displayed the preview, in the community, in the pop-up as wished:

```
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview'
            },
            state : {
                selectedRecordId: file.ContentDocumentId
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's showing pop up

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](
   {
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: recordId, // pass the record id here.
            actionName: 'edit',
        },
    });
```